# how to compare string values of dataframe and list of tuples

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe, tuples

I want to compare every string present in the list of tuples that match with the item in a dataframe. if there is a match then the word corresponding to word in the dataframe to be added to the tuple.

My list is like:

```
[('nan', 353), ('LEVEL SUBGROUPS', 12), (' SYSTEMS', 9), ('SYSTEMS', 8), (' PARALLEL ALGORITHMS', 7)]
```

My dataframe's columns are:

```
Index(['subject', 'theme', 'keys'], dtype='object')
```

I want to map each theme to the tuples by comparing the tuple value and "keys".

My piece of code is:

```
themes=[]
for each in list:
    if each[0]=='nan':
        continue
    else:
        for index,row in df.iterrows():
            if str(row["keys"])==str(each[0]):
                theme_89_93.append(str(row["theme"]))
```

when i am comparing the string values it isn't checking the values and never entering the if statement. Please let me know what i am doing wrong

Comment: Actually, with your code, if some row is like `row['keys']='SYSTEMS'`, you will append the value of `row['theme']` twice, since in the list there are two values that match with `'SYSTEMS'`: Is that intentionally or you only want to match the unique values of the list?

Comment: It'll be good if you consider accepting or upvoting an answer to reward those who helped you, or if there is something wrong you could leave a comment too ;) @AyushiSharma

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, You could try this instead, using `pd.Dataframe.isin()`:

```
themes=df[df['key'].isin([i for i in dict(ls).keys() if i!='nan'])].theme.values
```

Or this, just in case you have strings with trailing or leading spaces, in both,(`df.values` or `ls`)

```
themes=df[df['key'].str.strip().isin([i.strip() for i in dict(ls).keys() if i.strip()!='nan'])].theme.values
```

---

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([(1,'nan'),(3,'SYSTEMS'),(5,'PARALLEL ALGORITHMS')], columns=['theme','key'])

ls=[('nan', 353), ('LEVEL SUBGROUPS', 12), ('SYSTEMS', 9), ('SYSTEMS', 8), ('PARALLEL ALGORITHMS', 7)]

themes=df[df['key'].isin([i for i in dict(ls).keys() if i!='nan'])].theme.values
```

Output:

```
df
   theme                  key
0      1                  nan
1      3              SYSTEMS
2      5  PARALLEL ALGORITHMS

themes
[3 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if an item is in the index by

```
each[0] in df.index
```

if you want to specific test for the keys column in index you can do it like.

```
each[0] in df.index.levels[2]
```

this should also be faster then iterating over the hole DataFrame